# git pull without pulling the name of the repository?

Tags: git, github, branch, pull, repository

When I use the command

```
git clone git clone git@github.com:[my_org]/[my_repo].git
```

It comes down as my_repo/

I'd just like to pull the contents of the repo without pulling down the repo name as a folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This will clone into the current location that the command is being run (".") Alternatively you can provide your own directory name.

`git clone git@github.com:my_org/my_repo.git .`

`git clone git@github.com:my_org/my_repo.git path/to/myOwnDirName`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it always needs to go someplace, but you can specify your own directory name.
[Per the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html), the directory you specify can exist **only** if it is empty.

Here is sample command line to clone into directory name you choose:

```
git glone git@github.com:[my_org]/[my_repo].git path_to_directory
```